Convert the table into a record
I need to convert the table into a record in order to save it to SharePoint, is it possible to do this?
For example, I have a table like this:
Name       | Value
-----------------------
FirstItem  | FirstValue
SecondItem | SecondValue
ThirdItem  | ThirdValue

And I need to turn this list into a record like this:
{
    FirstItem: "FirstValue",
    SecondItem: "SecondValue",
    ThirdItem: "ThirdValue"
}

I spent several days searching and found nothing.
Maybe someone did this?

If you know the column names beforehand, then you can do something like the expression below.
{
    FirstItem: LookUp(MyTable, Name = "FirstItem", Value),
    SecondItem: LookUp(MyTable, Name = "SecondItem", Value),
    ThirdItem: LookUp(MyTable, Name = "ThirdItem", Value)
}

If you don't know, then you cannot create a record based on that. You may be able to create a string (text) with a JSON representation of that record, using something similar to this:
"{" &
  Concat(MyTable, JSON(Name) & ": " & JSON(Value), ", ") &
"}"

It's not a record per se, but in some scenarios it may be enough.

I don't know in advance what the fields will be. But thanks anyway:)

I believe JSON is still an experimental feature.

The JSON function has been out for many years, it's not experimental.
